# How to chain BCryptEncrypt and BCryptDecrypt calls using AES in GCM mode?

Tags: c, windows, aes-gcm, cng

Using the Windows CNG API, I am able to encrypt and decrypt individual blocks of data with authentication, using AES in GCM mode. I now want to encrypt and decrypt multiple buffers in a row.

According to [documentation for CNG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc562981(v=vs.85).aspx), the following scenario is supported:

> If the input to encryption or decryption is scattered across multiple
>   buffers, then you must chain calls to the BCryptEncrypt and
>   BCryptDecrypt functions. Chaining is indicated by setting the
>   BCRYPT_AUTH_MODE_IN_PROGRESS_FLAG flag in the dwFlags member.

If I understand it correctly, this means that I can invoke `BCryptEncrypt` sequentially on multiple buffers an obtain the authentication tag for the combined buffers at the end. Similarly, I can invoke `BCryptDecrypt` sequentially on multiple buffers while deferring the actual authentication check until the end. I can not get that to work though, it looks like the value for `dwFlags` is ignored. Whenever I use `BCRYPT_AUTH_MODE_IN_PROGRESS_FLAG`, I get a return value of `0xc000a002` , which is equal to `STATUS_AUTH_TAG_MISMATCH` as defined in `ntstatus.h`.

Even though the parameter `pbIV` is marked as in/out, the elements pointed to by the parameter `pbIV` do not get modified by `BCryptEncrypt()`. Is that expected? I also looked at the field `pbNonce` in the `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO` structure, pointed to by the `pPaddingInfo` pointer, but that one does not get modified either. I also tried "manually" advancing the IV, modifying the contents myself according to the counter scheme, but that did not help either.

What is the right procedure to chain the `BCryptEncrypt` and/or `BCryptDecrypt` functions successfully?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. It seems that the problem is in MSDN, it should mention setting `BCRYPT_AUTH_MODE_CHAIN_CALLS_FLAG` instead of `BCRYPT_AUTH_MODE_IN_PROGRESS_FLAG`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include <Bcrypt.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "bcrypt.lib")

std::vector<BYTE> MakePatternBytes(size_t a_Length)
{
    std::vector<BYTE> result(a_Length);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
    {
        result[i] = (BYTE)i;
    }

    return result;
}

std::vector<BYTE> MakeRandomBytes(size_t a_Length)
{
    std::vector<BYTE> result(a_Length);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
    {
        result[i] = (BYTE)rand();
    }

    return result;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    NTSTATUS bcryptResult = 0;
    DWORD bytesDone = 0;

    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE algHandle = 0;
    bcryptResult = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&algHandle, BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM, 0, 0);
    assert(BCRYPT_SUCCESS(bcryptResult) || !"BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider");

    bcryptResult = BCryptSetProperty(algHandle, BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE, (BYTE*)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM, sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM), 0);
    assert(BCRYPT_SUCCESS(bcryptResult) || !"BCryptSetProperty(BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE)");

    BCRYPT_AUTH_TAG_LENGTHS_STRUCT authTagLengths;
    bcryptResult = BCryptGetProperty(algHandle, BCRYPT_AUTH_TAG_LENGTH, (BYTE*)&authTagLengths, sizeof(authTagLengths), &bytesDone, 0);
    assert(BCRYPT_SUCCESS(bcryptResult) || !"BCryptGetProperty(BCRYPT_AUTH_TAG_LENGTH)");

    DWORD blockLength = 0;
    bcryptResult = BCryptGetProperty(algHandle, BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH, (BYTE*)&blockLength, sizeof(blockLength), &bytesDone, 0);
    assert(BCRYPT_SUCCESS(bcryptResult) || !"BCryptGetProperty(BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH)");

    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE keyHandle = 0;
    {
        const std::vector<BYTE> key = MakeRandomBytes(blockLength);
        bcryptResult = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(algHandle, &keyHandle, 0, 0, (PUCHAR)&key[0], key.size(), 0);
        assert(BCRYPT_SUCCESS(bcryptResult) || !"BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey");
    }

    const size_t GCM_NONCE_SIZE = 12;
    const std::vector<BYTE> origNonce = MakeRandomBytes(GCM_NONCE_SIZE);
    const std::vector<BYTE> origData  = MakePatternBytes(256);

    // Encrypt data as a whole
    std::vector<BYTE> encrypted = origData;
    std::vector<BYTE> authTag(authTagLengths.dwMinLength);
    {
        BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO authInfo;
        BCRYPT_INIT_AUTH_MODE_INFO(authInfo);
        authInfo.pbNonce = (PUCHAR)&origNonce[0];
        authInfo.cbNonce = origNonce.size();
        authInfo.pbTag   = &authTag[0];
        authInfo.cbTag   = authTag.size();

        bcryptResult = BCryptEncrypt
            (
            keyHandle,
            &encrypted[0], encrypted.size(),
            &authInfo,
            0, 0,
            &encrypted[0], encrypted.size(),
            &bytesDone, 0
            );

        assert(BCRYPT_SUCCESS(bcryptResult) || !"BCryptEncrypt");
        assert(bytesDone == encrypted.size());
    }

    // Decrypt data in two parts
    std::vector<BYTE> decrypted = encrypted;
    {
        DWORD partSize = decrypted.size() / 2;

        std::vector<BYTE> macContext(authTagLengths.dwMaxLength);

        BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO authInfo;
        BCRYPT_INIT_AUTH_MODE_INFO(authInfo);
        authInfo.pbNonce = (PUCHAR)&origNonce[0];
        authInfo.cbNonce = origNonce.size();
        authInfo.pbTag   = &authTag[0];
        authInfo.cbTag   = authTag.size();
        authInfo.pbMacContext = &macContext[0];
        authInfo.cbMacContext = macContext.size();

        // IV value is ignored on first call to BCryptDecrypt.
        // This buffer will be used to keep internal IV used for chaining.
        std::vector<BYTE> contextIV(blockLength);

        // First part
        authInfo.dwFlags = BCRYPT_AUTH_MODE_CHAIN_CALLS_FLAG;
        bcryptResult = BCryptDecrypt
            (
            keyHandle,
            &decrypted[0*partSize], partSize,
            &authInfo,
            &contextIV[0], contextIV.size(),
            &decrypted[0*partSize], partSize,
            &bytesDone, 0
            );

        assert(BCRYPT_SUCCESS(bcryptResult) || !"BCryptDecrypt");
        assert(bytesDone == partSize);

        // Second part
        authInfo.dwFlags &= ~BCRYPT_AUTH_MODE_CHAIN_CALLS_FLAG;
        bcryptResult = BCryptDecrypt
            (
            keyHandle,
            &decrypted[1*partSize], partSize,
            &authInfo,
            &contextIV[0], contextIV.size(),
            &decrypted[1*partSize], partSize,
            &bytesDone, 0
            );

        assert(BCRYPT_SUCCESS(bcryptResult) || !"BCryptDecrypt");
        assert(bytesDone == partSize);
    }

    // Check decryption
    assert(decrypted == origData);

    // Cleanup
    BCryptDestroyKey(keyHandle);
    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that makes sense. It does not seem to work though, I added some additional text about this to my question.

Comment: I have changed my answer completely.

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks. One remark: `trashIV` actually holds the advanced IV so is required for proper functioning in chaining mode. My mistake was that I had made the IV the same size as the nonce (in addition to using the 'wrong' `dwFlags` value).

Comment: OK, I didn't realize IV value is ignored on first call but then filled and used for chaining. Edited answer to reflect this for future readers.

Comment: Great example, one of the best can be found in google. The only suggestion is to not set key length same as block size. At all I don't clearly understand why you need to retrieve block size, for AES it always 16.

Comment: Two points: 
1) Quote : The cbIV parameter contains the size of this buffer. This function will modify the contents of this buffer. If you need to reuse the IV later, make sure you make a copy of this buffer before calling this function.
End_Quote. The documentation says this but I can find no mode for which it is actually modified.

2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

Says that 14 rounds are applied but BCrytEncrypt only performs one round. It would be good if this example was modified to support multiple rounds.

Answer (score 10):

@Codeguard's answer got me through the [project](https://gitlab.com/ubiqsecurity/ubiq-c-cpp/-/blob/master/src/lib/wincrypt.c) I was working on which lead me to find this question/answer in the first place; however, there were still a number of gotchas I struggled with. Below is the process I followed with the tricky parts called out. You can view the actual code at the link above:

1. Use `BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider` to open the algorithm provider using `BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM`.
2. Use `BCryptSetProperty` to set the `BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE` to `BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM`.
3. Use `BCryptGetProperty` to get the `BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH` to allocate for use by the BCrypt library for the encrypt/decrypt operation. Depending on your implementation, you may also want to:

   - Use `BCryptGetProperty` to determine `BCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE` and allocate scratch space for the IV. The Windows API updates the IV with each call, and the caller is responsible for providing the memory for that usage.
   - Use `BCryptGetProperty` to determine `BCRYPT_AUTH_TAG_LENGTH` and allocate scratch space for the largest possible tag. Like the IV, the caller is responsible for providing this space, which the API updates each time.
4. Initialize the `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO` struct:

   - Initialize the structure with `BCRYPT_INIT_AUTH_MODE_INFO()`
   - Initialize the `pbNonce` and `cbNonce` field. Note that for the first call to `BCryptEncrypt`/`BCryptDecrypt`, the IV is ignored as an input and this field is used as the "IV". However, the IV parameter will be updated by that first call and used by subsequent calls, so space for it must still be provided. In addition, the `pbNonce` and `cbNonce` fields must remain set (even though they are unused after the first call) for all calls to `BCryptEncrypt`/`BCryptDecrypt` or those calls will complain.
   - Initialize `pbAuthData` and `cbAuthData`. In my project, I set these fields just before the first call to `BCryptEncrypt`/`BCryptDecrypt` and immediately reset them to `NULL`/`0` immediately afterward. You can pass `NULL`/`0` as the input and output parameters during these calls.
   - Initialize `pbTag` and `cbTag`. `pbTag` can be `NULL` until the final call to `BCryptEncrypt`/`BCryptDecrypt` when the tag is retrieved or checked, but `cbTag` must be set or else `BCryptEncrypt`/`BCryptDecrypt` will complain.
   - Initialize `pbMacContext` and `cbMacContext`. These point to a scratch space for the `BCryptEncrypt`/`BCryptDecrypt` to use to keep track of the current state of the tag/mac.
   - Initialize `cbAAD` and `cbData` to `0`. The APIs use these fields, so you can read them at any time, but you should not update them after initially setting them to `0`.
   - Initialize `dwFlags` to `BCRYPT_AUTH_MODE_CHAIN_CALLS_FLAG`. After initialization, changes to this field should be made by using `|=` or `&=`. Windows also sets flags within this field that the caller needs to take care not to alter.
5. Use `BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey` to import the key to use for encryption/decryption. Note that you will need to supply the memory associated with `BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH` to this call for use by `BCryptEncrypt`/`BCryptDecrypt` during operation.
6. Call `BCryptEncrypt`/`BCryptDecrypt` with your AAD, if any; no input nor space for output need be supplied for this call. (If the call succeeds, you can see the size of your AAD reflected in the `cbAAD` field of the `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO` structure.)

   1. Set `pbAuthData` and `cbAuthData` to reflect the AAD.
   2. Call `BCryptEncrypt` or `BCryptDecrypt`.
   3. Set `pbAuthData` and `cbAuthData` back to `NULL` and `0`.
7. Call `BCryptEncrypt`/`BCryptDecrypt` "N - 1" times

   - The amount of data passed to each call **must** be a multiple of the algorithm's block size.
   - Do **not** set the `dwFlags` parameter of the call to anything other than `0`.
   - The output space must be equal to or greater than the size of the input
8. Call `BCryptEncrypt`/`BCryptDecrypt` one final time (with or without plain/cipher text input/output). The size of the input need not be a multiple of the algorithm's block size for this call. `dwFlags` is still set to `0`.

   1. Set the `pbTag` field of the `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO` structure either to the location at which to store the generated tag or to the location of the tag to verify against, depending on whether the operation is an encryption or decryption.
   2. Remove the `BCRYPT_AUTH_MODE_CHAIN_CALLS_FLAG` from the `dwFlags` field of the `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO` structure using the `&=` syntax.
9. Call `BCryptDestroyKey`
10. Call `BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider`

It would be wise, at this point, to wipe out the space associated with `BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH`.