# AES-256 GCM Encryption in C (bcrypt.h) does not decrypt in Python

Tags: python, c, aes-gcm

I'm trying to encrypt "Hello, world!" in C and decrypt in Python, the encryption process results in no errors, but the Python decryption errors with `ValueError: MAC check failed`, and can't seem to find the problem.

C Encryption code:

```c
NTSTATUS generateRandomBytes(BYTE *buffer, ULONG length) {
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hProvider;
    NTSTATUS status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hProvider, BCRYPT_RNG_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        return status;
    }

    status = BCryptGenRandom(hProvider, buffer, length, 0);
    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hProvider, 0);
    return status;
}


NTSTATUS encrypt_AES_GCM(const BYTE *plainData, ULONG plainDataLength,
                         const BYTE *iv, ULONG ivLength,
                         const BYTE *key, ULONG keyLength,
                         BYTE *encryptedData, ULONG encryptedDataLength)
{
    NTSTATUS status = 0;
    DWORD bytesDone = 0;
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE algHandle = 0;
    status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&algHandle, BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        return status;
    }

    status = BCryptSetProperty(algHandle, BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE, (PBYTE)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM, sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM), 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);
        return status;
    }

    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE keyHandle = 0;
    status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(algHandle, &keyHandle, NULL, 0, (PUCHAR)key, keyLength, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);
        return status;
    }

    BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO authInfo;
    BCRYPT_INIT_AUTH_MODE_INFO(authInfo);
    authInfo.pbNonce = (PUCHAR)iv;
    authInfo.cbNonce = ivLength;

    status = BCryptEncrypt(keyHandle, (PUCHAR)plainData, plainDataLength, &authInfo, NULL, 0, encryptedData, encryptedDataLength, &bytesDone, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        BCryptDestroyKey(keyHandle);
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);
        return status;
    }

    BCryptDestroyKey(keyHandle);
    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(algHandle, 0);

    return status;
}


int main() {
    char *input = "Hello, world!";
    BYTE key[32];
    BYTE iv[12];
    BYTE keyAndIV[44];
    BYTE *encrypted;
    ULONG encryptedSize = 14 + 16; // Input size (Hello, world!) is 14 bytes, and the automatically generated AAD is 16, so the output size is 30

    // Generate key n iv
    generateRandomBytes(key, sizeof(key));
    generateRandomBytes(iv, sizeof(iv));
    // Concatenate key and IV
    memcpy(keyAndIV, key, sizeof(key));
    memcpy(keyAndIV + sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));

    // Print the infoo
    printf("Key:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(key); i++) {
        printf("%02X", key[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("IV:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(iv); i++) {
        printf("%02X", iv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    encrypted = (BYTE *)malloc(encryptedSize);

    // Encrypt
    encrypt_AES_GCM((BYTE*)input, 14, iv, 12, key, 32, encrypted, encryptedSize);
    printf("Encrypted bytes:\n");
    for (ULONG i = 0; i < encryptedSize; i++) {
        printf("%02X", encrypted[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(encrypted);
    return 0;
}
```

And the Python code:

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = bytes.fromhex('')
iv = bytes.fromhex('')
authTag = bytes.fromhex('')
ciphertext = bytes.fromhex('')

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=iv)
plaintext = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, authTag)
print("Decrypted plaintext:", plaintext.decode('utf-8'))
```

Example outputs of both:
C

```
Key:
14D63CB4BDE1A3D164DB09E44B6C877613CB7C0E281148653BE3EDFC9D476C73
IV:
27FEF35218E2FC4391971C5F
Encrypted bytes:
A0660CFE8F01000050010CFE8F0100003A5C50726F6772616D2046696C65
```

Python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Projects\Testing code\test.py", line 64, in <module>
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, authTag)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_gcm.py", line 567, in decrypt_and_verify
    self.verify(received_mac_tag)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_gcm.py", line 508, in verify
    raise ValueError("MAC check failed")
ValueError: MAC check failed
```

**The Python data is all added from the C output, the auth tag is set to the last 16 bytes of the encrypted data, and the first 14 as the ciphertext**

I have tried changing the iv to 12x A's and made the key simpler, so seems to be a problem with the authentication tag.

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Where are you setting the key and iv in the decryption code?

Comment: Should `char input = "Hello, world!";` in `int main() {...}` be `char *input = "Hello, world!";`?

Comment: @FrankYellin It's randomly generated

Comment: Yes @ChrisFu my bad, had forgot to change that!

Comment: During testing you could make things simpler and use hardcoded values in both source snippets.

Comment: @Gerhardh That could be an great idea, but in the end the iv and key will have to be generated on the run anyways, which seems to work well. But indeed in this testing I'm hardcoding them to the Python script.

Comment: `BCryptEncrypt()` does not append the **AEAD** tag (not "AAD" - that's something else) to the ciphertext - silently appending the AES/GCM tag is mostly from Java's benighted AES/GCM implementation. You need to set the `pbTag` and `cbTag` fields of the [`BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_authenticated_cipher_mode_info) struct to obtain the tag from the call to `BCryptEncrypt()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720414/how-to-chain-bcryptencrypt-and-bcryptdecrypt-calls-using-aes-in-gcm-mode for an example.

Comment: @AndrewHenle This explained a lot and solved the problem!